# HTML/JS app - getting a reference to an element which is not part of the DOM

Tags: javascript

I am trying to debug an app which I don't own which uses HTML5 and JS, which displays a video stream.  The issue is that the video stutters when viewed in high resolution.

Note that the code is obfuscated, but has been prettyfied which helps a little.  So far using Chrome developer tools and by injecting listeners I have determined that the video is being displayed in a `<canvas>` element.  From my research, I have determined that displaying video content in `<canvas>` requires the use of `<video>`, where the data taken from the video element is manipulated and written on to the `<canvas>`.

My problem is that I want to get a reference to the `<video>` element, which apparently is not a part of the DOM.  The use of Chrome developer tools reveals no such element, nor does `getElementsByTagName()`.  I find clues in the code which indicate a `<video>` element most likely exists, so my conclusion is that it is just used in memory as a tool and is not added to the DOM.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can get a reference to this element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Look for any requests to `document.createElement` or `document.createElementNS` in the code that may be creating and appending the `<video>` element to the DOM. You might be able to locate the `<video>` element by searching the child nodes of its parent element.
- Look for any event listeners associated with the `<video>` element. For example, if the `<video>` element has a onended event listener, you could try triggering it and seeing if it produces any output in the console or other visible effects.
- Search the code for any mentions of the `<video>` element. You might notice references to an attribute in the code, for instance, if the `src` attribute of the `<video>` element is set dynamically.
- You might be able to locate the `<video>` element by looking for it in the virtual DOM or component tree if the code makes use of a JavaScript library or framework (like React or Angular).
- If the `<video>` element is being used to display a video stream from a server, you may be able to locate it by inspecting the network traffic in the developer tools. For example, if the video stream is served via the HTML5 `MediaSource` API, network requests for video segments should be visible in the network panel.